# Using __add__ operator with multiple arguments in Python

Tags: python, class, overloading, addition, operator-keyword

I am trying to add a class object with a number, but I'm confused on how to go about adding a class object with two numbers. For example, this is my hypothetical **add** class method:

```
class A:
    def __add__(self, b):
        return something
```

I know how to add this so far:

```
a = A()
print(a + 1)
```

But, what if I want to add it like this?

```
a = A()
print(a + 1 + 2)
```

Should I use *args for the **add** class method?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, you can't use multiple arguments. Python executes each `+` operator separately, the two `+` operators are distinct expressions.

For your example, `object + 1 + 2` really is `(object + 1) + 2`. If `(object + 1)` produces an object that has an `__add__` method, then Python will call that method for the second operator.

You could, for example, return another instance of `A` here:

```
>>> class A:
...     def __init__(self, val):
...         self.val = val
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return f'<A({self.val})>'
...     def __add__(self, other):
...         print(f'Summing {self} + {other}')
...         return A(self.val + other)
...
>>> A(42) + 10
Summing A(42) + 10
<A(52)>
>>> A(42) + 10 + 100
Summing A(42) + 10
Summing A(52) + 100
<A(152)>
```

Comment: Shouldn't an implemetation of __radd__ also be added here? Also, in the case of 1 + 2 + 3, is the implementation (1.__add__(2)).__add__(3) or 1.__add__(2.__add__(3))?

Comment: @NM: That's not a *requirement*, not to answer the question at any rate.

Comment: @NM: and `__radd__` is only going to be called if the LHS refused to handle the operation or if the RHS is a subclass of the LHS type. `1 + 2 + 3` is `(1).__add__(2).__add__(3)`.

Comment: @NM: to word it differently, for `LHS + RHS`, for `not issubclass(type(RHS), type(LHS))`, `LHS.__add__(RHS)` is called first, and if that doesn't exist or returns `NotImplemented` *only then* is `RHS.__radd__(LHS)` tried. The subclass exception is there to make it possible to subclass existing types and 'capture' the operator hook.

Answer (score 5):

You would want your return value to be an object itself, that also supports the add operation, e.g.:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, value=0):
        self.value = value

    def __add__(self, b):
        return A(self.value + b)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value)

a = A()
print(a + 1 + 2)
```

Output:

> 3

Answer (score 2):

It perfectly works even with multiple values since each add only adds two values (see the multiple + signs when you ad multiple values):

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.a = value
    def __add__(self, another_value):
        return self.a + another_value


a = A(1)
print(a+1+1)
```

Comment: In this case the last add operation is not handled by the A class anymore but is a simple addition of 2 (returned by A.__add__) and 1.

Comment: Yes you are right, but since 1 and 2 are numbers this is what should happen. If the author wanted to add two class instances then the example would not have been a+1 but a+b (a and b being instances of A)...

Answer (score 2):

you could always just do this:

```
>>> class A:
...     def __init__(self, val):
...         self.val = val
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return f'<A({self.val})>'
...     def __add__(self, other):
...         print(f'Summing {self} + {other}')
...         return A(self.val + other)
...
>>> A(42) + 10
Summing A(42) + 10
<A(52)>
>>> A(42) + 10 + 100
Summing A(42) + 10
Summing A(52) + 100
<A(152)>>>> class A:
...     def __init__(self, val):
...         self.val = val
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return f'<A({self.val})>'
...     def __add__(self, other):
...         print(f'Summing {self} + {other}')
...         return A(self.val + other)
...
>>> A(42) + 10
Summing A(42) + 10
<A(52)>
>>> A(42) + 10 + 100
Summing A(42) + 10
Summing A(52) + 100
<A(152)>
```

Comment: does this help?